# Append dataframes to a list ouside of multiprocessing target function

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing for reading csv and adding them together. In this case it can be unsorted.This code I have used but apperently the dataframe cant be added to the data for some reason. I have also tried `data=data.append(tb,ignore_index=True)`. I also tried with `global data` within the function but I still get no outcome.

```
files=[]
for x in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    files.append(x)

data = pd.DataFrame()

def opener(file):
    tb=pd.read_csv(file)
    data.append(tb,ignore_index=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(8)
    p.map(opener, files)
    p.close()
    p.join()

print(data)
```

I get only

```
Empty DataFrame 
Columns: [] 
Index: []
```

Comment: You can't send data between processes merely by using variables that have the same name in each process.  You have to use the specific mechanisms that `multiprocessing` provides for this purpose (sorry, I'm not personally familiar enough with the module to make any specific recommendation in your case).

Comment: I understand but do you know how to append an item to a list which is ouside of a function?

Comment: You can't really use `Pool` here! I would recommend you to split the informations in your csv. file into little chunks. After that you should use `starmap_async` because with that you can send the chunk as the first argument and the list as the second argument

Comment: @TornaxO7 the only possible way i can think of right now is pd.read_csv(file,chunks=chunks). Is that what you mean?

Comment: uff! I don't really now the DataFrame-method. But what I mean is like that:

csvFile = "This is a text"
chunks = list(csvFile.split(" ")) 

now the csvFile is splittet into little chunks

After splitting them you can give them as a parameter to the `starmap_async` function

Comment: You are successfully "appending an item to a list which is ouside of a function" already!  The problem is that each process has its own separate list, none of which is the list that you're printing out in the main process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a dataframe as a shared data structure in `multiprocessing` approach would be quite problematic cause a shared structure needs to be pickled/packed and passed to each `Process` run in parallel.
Instead, pass a shared list as process-safe [`multiprocessing.Manager.list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) to accumulate dataframes which then will be concatenated in one pass with `pd.concat` invocation:

By the way, `pd.concat` should be a preferred approach in comparing to (`pd.DataFrame()` + multiple `.append()` calls).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import glob
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

def csv_to_df(lst, fname):
    lst.append(pd.read_csv(fname))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dfs_list = Manager().list()
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    files = glob.iglob('*.csv')
    res = pool.map_async(partial(csv_to_df, dfs_list), files)
    res.wait()
    dfs = pd.concat(dfs_list, ignore_index=True)  # the final result
    print(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying different ways I managed to run the multiprocessing for opening csv files somehow like this:

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

files = []
for x in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    files.append(x)

def data_pool(file):
    return pd.read_csv(file)

data = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4)
    data = pd.concat(p.map(data_pool, files)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It brings the same performance like the solution of @RomanPerekhrest but I think its usefull to share it with the community as an alternative solution.